# Setting Printform.BodyContainer in C#.NET

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, currently working with PrintForm. I would like to know as to how to set the PrintForm.BodyContainer property to refer the current Form in visual studio 2010.

Comment: That's a pretty obscure component, use the vendor's support channels to find help.  http://www.winformreports.co.uk/contactus.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.PrintForm.BodyContainer = this;
```

Comment: How can this be done via the GUI of visual studio and not via code?